# Backup and restoration of Mautic

Tags: automation, backup, restore, database-backups, mautic

I am a beginner in IT and Web Development.

I would like to create a backup of the Mautic installed on a hosting server “A” and restore it in another server “B”. How do I do that?
If it’s possible to automate the backup and the restoration, please tell me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the Following to Back up and Restore your Mautic.

1. Zip you Current Directory then Download
2. Export your Maultic Database

on Server B

1. Creat Db
2. Import your Current Db
3. Upload Mautic Files to the domain folder you wanna use.
4. change Db Connection in app/config/local.php

These should fix the ish.

Comment: Hello @iam_migher and thank you for your reply. Is it possible to automate the above steps?

Comment: That sounds too good to be true, is it really THAT easy?